# How to prevent large file POST requests using Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How to prevent large file requests using Azure APIM?

Example: Block any POST request having file size > 50MB

Comment: If you can rely on the Content-Length header to be correctly filled, you could filter on that (I know, not a perfect solution, but an easy one)

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#SetUsageQuota.

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/route-requests-based-on-size

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the following policy for all your APIs. For each POST request, the policy will check the body size, and if the size is above 50MB, it will return status 413 - Payload Too Large.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Method == "POST")">
                <set-variable name="bodySize" value="@(context.Request.Headers["Content-Length"][0])" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("bodySize"))<52428800)">
                        <!--let it pass through by doing nothing-->
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="413" reason="Payload Too Large" />
                            <set-body>@{
                                    return "Maximum allowed size for the POST requests is 52428800 bytes (50 MB). This request has size of "+ context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("bodySize") +" bytes";
                                } 
                            </set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are policies called **quota-by-Key** and **quota-by-subscription** , which will help the users to block the calls that exceed the bandwidth specified. Please verify this link for more details.[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#SetUsageQuota)